# adding more than one list item into List at a time when the items are generated dynamically (using NAPA)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using the below code to insert an item into the list.

```
    function createitem() {
     var selectListBox = document.getElementById("txtFormName");
     var selectedListTitle = selectListBox.value;
     var selectedList = web.get_lists().getByTitle(selectedListTitle);

     var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
     var newItem = selectedList.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);

     newItem.set_item('Title','abc');
     newItem.update();
     context.load(newItem);
     context.executeQueryAsync(onItemCreationSuccess, onItemCreationFail);
     }
```

Its working fine. Now I want to use

```
    newItem.set_item('Title1','def');
    newItem.set_item('Title2','xyz');
    .
    .
    .
    and so on
```

in loop for more than one item in the same row to insert. How can i achieve that. kindly guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SharePoint CSOM API supports [Request Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx)  the following example demonstrate how to create multiple list items using a *single* request to the server:

```
function createListItem(context,listTitle,itemProperties)
{
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    for(var propName in itemProperties) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProperties[propName]) 
    }
    listItem.update();
    return listItem;
}



//Usage
var contactItems = [];
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var contactProperties  = {'Title': 'Doe','FirstName': 'John'};

//1.Prepare multiple list items
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   var contactItem = createListItem(context,'Contacts',contactProperties);
   contactItems.push(contactItem);
}   
//2. Submit request to the server to create list items
context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          console.log(contactItems.length + ' contacts have been created');        
      },
      function(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
      }
   );
```

Key points:

- List Item creation operations are submitted to the server in a single
  request using `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` method